# Multiple Linear regression- Improving R square

Tags: python

I have a dataset based on a chemical experiment

```
x1        x2       supplier         results
180     20        1                56.0
180     20        1                76.5
180     20        0                67
180     20        1                70
180     40        0                67.2
200     20        0                65.2
200     20        1                74.0
```

I have used multiple regression to predict the model. Before fitting I have converted the supplier values into numerical values. I have tried to fit in with all 3 features.

```
lm1 = smf.ols(formula='Results~ x1+  x2 + Suppliers', data=df).fit()

lm1.rsquared = 0.824
```

I tried to evaluate with train and test data

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

print('Train:', X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print('Test:' , X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

# Instantiate model
lm2 = LinearRegression()

# Fit model
lm2.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict
y_pred = lm2.predict(X_test)
```

The score for train is: 0.8087028362625359
The score for test is: 0.8584019897255022

Then performed cross-validation.

```
predictions = cross_val_predict(lm2, X, y, cv=5)
```

and received an accuracy of 0.80%

The question is how to improve accuracy. The expected r square should be around 96%. Is there anything I can do to improve it.

Comment: Seems like a better question for [stats.se] or [datascience.se] but both sites will expect you to also describe what you've tried based on your own research

Answer (score 0):

Trying using RidgeRegression that will lead to better results.

Comment: But one thing i observe in data . same supplier with same experiment yields different results.                                                                                                                               
                180     20        1                56.0
                 180     20        1                76.5                                                                                               . Is there anything i need to do as part of preprocessing

Comment: I just tried with Ridge regression. I got 0.85 as the score.